# Upgrade Windows Server 2008 R2 to Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2012

Is it possible to upgrade to Windows Server 2012 R2 from Windows Server 2008 R2? Our Windows Server 2008 R2 has a valid license key.

I do not have the installation media for Windows Server 2012 R2. If I download the Windows Server 2012 R2 Evaluation installer, will it recognize my Windows Server 2008 R2 license keys?

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, Yes, but some of the configuration will lost.

For your second question, sadly, your Windows Server 2008 R2 licence cannot be used to activate a copy of Windows Server 2012 R2. And the evaluation installer may not contain the image of a retail or volume licencing version installer.

Comment: So does this mean that I have to buy a new license for the newer Windows Server OS?

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b Yes, you have to OWN already a License-Key for a different Version, it's not a "i can buy once, own every version" Each Product has its Version and License so far, you have to buy it.